# Временные таблицы MySQL для представлений

Tags: mysql, view, temporary-table

Я нашла в дампе базы данных скрипт для создания временных таблиц для представлений:

```
--
-- Temporary table structure for view `payments`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `payments`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `payments`*/;
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned zerofill,
  ...
  `allow` tinyint(1),
  `receipt` blob
) */;
```

И у меня возник когнитивный диссонанс. Я всегда раньше думала, что временные таблицы создаются только во время выполнения запросов. Но тогда почему временные таблицы MySQL для представлений сохраняются в дампе? С представлениями для базы данных я в принципе раньше никогда не работала и никакой информации по теме временных таблиц поводу для них я не нашла, так что буду благодарна, если поможете понять!

Comment: Что-то не видно временных таблиц. Просто сносятся таблица и представление, в случае их существования, перед созданием таблицы обычной payments.

Comment: Уважаемая Ксения! Похоже, вы неправильно перевели комментарий - Temporary table structure это "временная структура таблицы", а не "структура временной таблицы". А временных таблиц в процитированном вами фрагменте нет, только представление (view)

Comment: А что тогда значит "временная структура таблицы"?